# Why is PHP slowing down my page load?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    content
    </body>
</html>
```

As an .html file, it loads in 16ms. As a php file, it loads in 5s. Actually, in DevTools it loads much faster, but the throbber keeps spinning for 4.x seconds and then the load time changes to 5.x seconds. It seems to be a php issue, but what is going on? What should I check? It is a blocker, because the real page has an accordion that will not become clickable until the browser releases!

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: What kind of php you have for the backend? Framework or simple scripts? Do you have db connection?

Comment: Does it exhibit the same behavior in different browsers?

Comment: This is the complete code tested. Shared win server. php is also a host service.

Comment: If you modify the handler so PHP handles HTML as well does this go to 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Please use Google PageSpeed Tools. It will analyze your page to find what's slowing down your page. You may try Yslow Tools too (browser addon)

[Page Speed Tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?csw=1)

[yslow.org](http://yslow.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but this appears to be a server tool. Unfortunately, I am on a shared win server. php is also a host service.

Comment: Re PageSpeed...I will try Yslow.

Comment: I installed yslow and it does look helpful. It is telling me I have "misconfigured ETags" and perhaps some cookie and image issues. However, further investigation shall occur after the weekend, which starting now has first priority on resources. Meh.